# TextEdit not responding after zooming in

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, textedit

Recently, i noticed TextEdit on macos bigsur(M1 chip) taking more than 3GB ram and is not responding after I try zooming in.
Even though my .txt wasn't very big(just 4KB, barely 50 lines of text). Anyone experiencing the same, please respond? Is that a bug ?[image]
The ram consumption is increasing exponentially unless I force quit the app. Its working absolutely fine if I don't zoom into it.

Edit : It happens with any text file with TextEdit which is a bit large, e.g more than 50-60 lines. For .txt files with lesser content, its not happening.

Comment: Have you the same problem with any Textedit file or only with one? I've no problem with zooming function in Textedit on my MBA M1. You can first try boot your Mac in SafeMode. That clean somes system caches : support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/… Then reboot in "normal mode".

Comment: Not tried with other editors

Comment: i can send you the .txt file which I opened, maybe there's limit in number of characters there, exceeding which this error comes.

Comment: That was not the question. In Textedit if you create new file, have you the same problem? Else yes you can give here a download link and i will try with you file. Sorry i would be absent for somes hours. ;-)

Comment: Event:            hang
Duration:         20.28s
Duration Sampled: 1.00s (process was unresponsive for 19 seconds before sampling)
Steps:            10 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:   MacBookAir10,1
Active cpus:      8

Time Awake Since Boot: 116512s
Time Since Wake:  295s

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozUX8ZSOEUnsv3Fbiz8rfeVwh0Woolzz/view?usp=sharing (link to the file)

Comment: Please edit and update your question with the following info: Does this always happen with TextEdit? Or does it only happen with this particular file? When this is happening, open `Console` app and click on the *Errors and Faults* tab - is any obvious error listed? Search for "TextEdit" in `Console` app - is any error or fault listed?

Comment: Yeah, updated. You can try this on your own machine. Download this .txt [link] **(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ozUX8ZSOEUnsv3Fbiz8rfeVwh0Woolzz/view)**  or make your own with more than 60-70 lines of text and then try to zoom in out multiple times and see how the ram usage increases. After that, a point comes when it stops responding, and ram occupancy increases exponentially.

Comment: I've just download and test your txt file in Textedit (version 1.16) Big Sur 11.3.1 on MBA M1. It's work like a charm :) No cpu or memory high consommation.  Have you try a Safe Boot?

Comment: I tried in a different MacBook as well (borrowed from friend, same configuration). He faced same issue, problem is when you have a sufficiently large file like the one above and you do zoom in out multiple times, then this happens. For once or twice, this won't be an issue. But doing it repeatedly for few seconds, the application will not respond for sure.

Comment: This exact problem just started happening to me too. Using the trackpad to zoom in/out causes the issue almost immediately. It seems like scrolling is also causing TextEdit to freeze in some instances. Did you ever find a solution @MohitAgarwala?

Comment: Just found this--looks like we're not alone: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/676755

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for not providing the answer. I just want to confirm that the issue is really happening.

Today, I had a meeting with my client. I noted important content in TextEditor and I haven't saved it yet. After the meeting, I did several zoom-in and zoom-out. And suddenly, TextEditor became not responding and it has been eating more and more RAM (current is 23.14 GB).

I would thank you a lot if anyone tells me how can I restore/save the currently opening content. If I force killing the process, I think everything will be lost.

Oh my god, Apple. Please don't do this to me! :'(

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have something really important, try taking screenshot or pic from mobile. I don't think there's any way to recover it if it doesn't get saved automatically. But I think it gets saved.

Comment: thanks for your advice. actually, my PC doesn't get frozen. Only the TextEdit is frozen. There are 75% of the note is currently appear and I already saved by screenshot. Btw, TextEdit is currently eating 71G+ RAM. I am going to kill it now :'(

Comment: Yeah, do it asap

Comment: TextEdit uses Apple's 'automatic' document method, so all documents, even Untitled ones, are saved as you go along. You can ForceQuit the app and you should not lose anything.

Comment: actually. After forcing quitting, and re-open the application again, all the notes were there. Thank you all for your comments.